# help to decipher wp metadata

Tags: post-meta, user-meta

I am having problems trying to decipher the metadata information.

What does all the a: , s: stuff mean?

is there a place where i can reference what all this coding means in wp?

not just for attachment metadata, but users, etc.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is serialized data. To save an array to MySQL the data is serialized upon submission, so the best way to read that data is to pull it out of the database with a function that unserializes it, which WordPress does for you. [More details](http://nacin.com/2010/04/18/wordpress-serializing-data/)

So somewhere in a theme or plugin you could just use [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) to print the array of data for any given user.

Comment: thanks for that reference, it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but it did click something for me...a is array, s is string the ":n" after the a or s is some sort of reference number for an attribute that depends upon the context. The ':"text"' is the value. - I went to edit but timed out - sorry for any repeat.